# how can I delete ENTER from Between lines of a text file with use BAT file?

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a text file. Inside that file are many lines but between each line is a surplus ENTER (space). I want to delete that surplus SPACE. How can I do this with a bat file?

For example:

Current text in my text file

[image: current text]

I want to convert it like this

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each line of the input file (in the following example `input.txt`), and write all lines that do not only contain `\r\n` to the output file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (input.txt) do (
    if not %%i == "\r\n" echo %%i>> output.txt
)
```

Comment: thanks for your response .
but this code not working :(
could you please check this structure ?

@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (c:\1.txt) do (
    if not %%i == "\r\n" echo %%i>> c:\2.txt
)

is it correct ?
i want to edit my root file ,just 1 file .is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to run it as a `.bat` file the above code should work, if you want to just copy-paste it to the command line and run it from there, remove the first line and replace `%%i` by `%i`: `for /f "tokens=*" %i in (in.txt) do (if not %i == "\r\n" echo %i>> out.txt)`

Comment: oh, and since this will always create a second file, you could add 2 more lines that delete the original file and rename the output file: `del in.txt` and `ren out.txt in.txt`

Comment: Regrettably, this answer works by failing to fail. `\r\n` is simply a string in `CMD` - it has no particular significance. The `FOR /F` will remove empty lines; the `if not...` is worse than completely superfluous. It will delete any lines that contain the specific literal `\r\n` - that's a literal string, not a newline-sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
findstr /r /v /c:"^$" input.txt > output.txt
```

Read `input.txt` and output to `output.txt` lines that does not match the regular expression: *start of line (`^`) followed by end of line (`$`)*

Comment: I think, this is the fastest solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in (oldfile.txt) do @echo %i>>newfile.txt
```

replace `%i` with `%%i` when you use it inside a batchfile.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (inputfile.txt) do echo(%%a>>outputfile.txt
```

Although the last line will also acquire a terminal newline sequence.